# Appending with variable div size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let’s say I have this theoretical problem where I need to append several different variable div sizes to a container.

Here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf508.png.

Now let’s say I want div number 48 to append directly after number 47 (underneath div 33).

Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcSDD.png.

Would this be possible at all? And if not what would the alternatives be?

My lis if anyone is interested:

```
<li class="ui-state-default listitem smallbox">
   <div style="background-color: #D305ED" class="inner">1</div>
</li>
```

Edit: What if I also wanted to use the JQuery UI library to allow me to move the divs around on the screen. Would it still be possible to use packery or masonry in this scenario?

Comment: You really need a smart container (like isotope or masonry) to layout items with any intelligence. A D.I.Y. alternative is using a table with rolspan and colspans set.

Comment: You would be handling this logic in javasccript/jquery. There are a bunch of libraries that do this very well, unless you are required to build this from the ground up I would recommend checking out isotope/masonry

Comment: You should look at the masonry js plugin http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the positioning in rendering time.

To make it easier, check the Jquery plugin Masonry:
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Care to explain what you mean by "You have to calculate the positioning in rendering time"?

Comment: You should use javascript to get the width and height of all boxes in your container, and then calculate a new positioning for the boxes without get blank spaces. It's not a simple calculation, but there is some plugins (like Masonry) which can do this "hard" work for you.

Comment: I meant *reword your answer* as that line makes little sense at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is dynamic, you could use [packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/) or [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which are designed to layout items with few gaps.

If it is a static layout you could create the effect by filling a table and tracking the col and rolspan of the cells. The logic to look-ahead is complex, so you may want to try the following two-step approach:

As your example seems to only have 2 sizes (single and double-size), you could create a 2d array and progressively fill the cells with the item numbers, based on the sizes. This is a very rough version of what packery does on a pixel basis. Once you have the array filled, you then generate the output based on the array (in table TRs/TDs or DIVs with absolute positioning).

Comment: Would these approaches work in conjunction with Jquery UI drag and drop functions?

Comment: @Treebeards: `packery` is draggable. I suggest you try that one first.